# "rm -rf Filename.iso " Permission denied

Tags: permissions, files, rm

Hi I am facing an issue while deleting an .iso file from `Linux x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Here are the permissions for the file:

```
    # ls -lrt
    -rwxrwxr-x 1 dev devgrp 2687934464 Apr 12 14:13 FileName.iso*
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
    # rm -f FilsName.iso
    rm: cannot remove `FileName.iso': Permission denied
```

How to resolve this Permission denied error? I am logged in as `root` user.

---

EDIT

```
$ lsattr
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on ./FileName.02.md5
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on ./FileName.02.iso
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on ./FileName.03.md5
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on ./FileName.03.iso
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on ./FileName.04.iso
```

---

Strange issuse for me I can delete/move other files except `FileName.04.iso`.

Comment: I was going to add as answer that the `.iso` file might be mounted in loopback mode. But I tried and you **can** actually `rm` the file from underneath an existing loopback mount.

Comment: Could you please clarify more? Thanks

Comment: Your `touch test`, assuming `test` is next to `FilsName.iso` is taking care of Hauke's test nr 1. That does not apply.

Comment: My comment was based on the fact that I thought that if you mount the filesystem in the `.iso` file (which most likely is a file with a cdrom image) that you cannot delete that file. But that is wrong.

Comment: @Anthon You cannot delete the file, indeed. You can delete a directory entry. But as long as the file is opened the reference count in the inode is not set to 0 (which causes the real deletion of the file). This can lead to the strange situation that `df` tells you that a file system is nearly full but you cannot find the files which sum up to that capacity. Doing this with a kernel module is probably even more fun as to my knowledge you don't have any chance to determine that from userspace. The other ones can still be seen (and accessed / rescued) via `/proc/*/fd`

Comment: This is getting strange. What file system is this?

Comment: using ext3 filesystem

Comment: The error message doesn't make any sense to me. What kind of device is that? Please run `e2fsck -fy` on it (after unmounting).

Comment: its ext3 filesystem. I can't unmount the device as so many users are currently accessing the same device.

Comment: @Hauke Are you sure you were not mixing things up in the comment on my comment? (I **could** delete the file, did not try to delete the directory before unmounting though). I propose I delete my confusing thread of comments from this unclear (until now) problem as it does not really contribute, but does distract.

Comment: `df -h` and `mount | grep YOURFILESYSTEM` does show what?

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -ld .` in the directory containing the file. Also please copy-paste the exact command you ran (`FilsName.iso`, really?).

Answer (score 3):

Usually this is not about the access rights of the file but about those of its parent directory (because deleting the file means deleting the entry in the file list; for this the directory has to be written). You need write access to the parent.

Under normal conditions this would not affect root. root can be blocked by

1. read-only mounts
2. special file system attributes (immutable flag, see `lsattr`)
3. **Edit:** file system errors - run fsck
4. kernel security features (AppArmor, SELinux)

I would check in this order.

Comment: Thanks Hauke for answer. for further clarification I can `touch test` and I can easily delete `rm -f test`. It indicates that the directory has write access.
But don't know why am unable to delete .iso file in the same directory?

Comment: @Check_MK Why don't you do what I told you? Quoting myself: "see lsattr".

Comment: ahh by mistake i entered -r option in `rm` command. I updated the question accordingly. It still not permitted for `rm -f file`

Comment: updated the `lsattr` output in question

Comment: @Check_MK The last lines of `strace rm -f FilsName.iso`, please (especially `unlinkat()...`).

Comment: you meant to run `strace rm -f FileName.iso`, strace - command not found

Comment: @Check_MK Oh that's pretty cool. Who would ever need strace on a server... So what about installing it?

Comment: Am sorry I can't change/install the packages. Wouldn't it possible without installing `strace`?

Comment: Just guessing, but do you have `gdb` installed?

Comment: Thanks @Michael for ur comment.....Nope `gdb` is also not installed.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Strange issuse for me I can delete/move other files except `FileName.04.iso`.

Comment: @Check_MK `e2fsck` is your friend. Can you make a snapshot of the device so that you can fsck the volume without unmounting? That will not solve the problem, just show us whether it's a FS error. After the fsck you can mount the snapshot read-write and tr to delete the file.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: Updated the question in `EDIT 2` with `fsck` output.

Comment: @Check_MK Let me sum up: You don't know what snapshots are and rather happily destroy all your data than ask.